# regexp_matches() returns two matches for $ (end of string)

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Can somebody explain this odd behavior of [**`regexp_matches()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in PostgreSQL 9.2.4 (same result in 9.1.9):

```
db=# SELECT regexp_matches('test string', '$') AS end_of_string;
 end_of_string
---------------
 {""}
(1 row)

db=# SELECT regexp_matches('test string', '$', 'g') AS end_of_string;
 end_of_string
---------------
 {""}
 {""}
(2 rows)
```

[-> SQLfiddle demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1307)

The second parameter is a regular expression. `$` marks the end of the string.
The third parameter is for flags. `g` is for "globally", meaning the the function doesn't stop at the first match.

The function seems to report the end of the string *twice* with the `g` flag, but that can only exist *once* per definition. It breaks my query. :(
Am I missing something?

---

I would need my query to return *one* more row at the end, for any possible string. I expected this query to do the job, but it adds *two* rows:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('test & foo/bar', '(&|/|$)', 'ig'))[1] AS delim
```

I know how to manually add a row, but I want to let the function take care of it.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `SELECT regexp_matches('test string', '$', 'g');` ?

Comment: @hwnd: Yes. The column alias doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: I haven't PostgreSQL here, but have you tried to use `\Z` instead of `$`

Comment: @M42: Thanks, but same result with `\Z`. You can use [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1315) to test online.

Comment: I note that your example returns only one row in my psql (9.5.3) - maybe it was a bug that was fixed?

Comment: @user9645: Indeed! Seems to have been fixed in Postgres 9.3. You might want to elaborate in an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in PostgreSQL. I verified for sure it is fixed in 9.3.8.  Looking at the release notes, I see possible references in:

### 9.3.4

> - Allow regular-expression operators to be terminated early by query
>     cancel requests (Tom Lane)
>
>   This prevents scenarios wherein a pathological regular expression
>     could lock up a server process uninterruptably for a long time.

### 9.3.6

> - Fix incorrect search for shortest-first regular expression matches
>     (Tom Lane)
>
>   Matching would often fail when the number of allowed iterations is
>     limited by a ? quantifier or a bound expression.

Thanks to Erwin for narrowing it down to 9.3.x.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what I am going to say because I don't use PostgreSQL so this is just me thinking out loud.

Since you are trying to match the end of string/line `$`, then in the first situation the outcome is expected, but when you turn on global match modifier `g` and because matching the end of line character doesn't actually consume or read any characters from the input string then the next match attempt will start where the first one left off, that is at the end of string and this will cause an infinite loop if it kept going like that so PostgreSQL engine might be able to detect this and stop it to prevent a crash or an infinite loop.

I tested the same expression in RegexBuddy with POSIX ERE flavor and it caused the program to become unresponsive and crash and this is the reason for my reasoning.

Comment: Interesting. Would you have an idea for an alternative expression that matches *once* at the end of the string? I need my query to return *one* additional one additional row. Added a bit to my question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am sorry i couldn't reply earlier. I looked a bit for a possible solution but the only thing i came up with was similar to yours, another possible solution that might work is using the special (start of match/end of match) meta-character which is denoted as \G in most regex flavors but I couldn't find with PostgreSQL flavor. Anyway don't bother too much looking for it cause it might not work too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that has been fixed in Postgres 9.3. See accepted answer.

---

For Postgres 9.2 or older: A halfway decent workaround for my situation would be to use the expression `.$` instead - matches for any string once at the last character:

```
WITH x(id, t) AS (
   VALUES
    (1, 'test & foo/bar')
   ,(2, 'test')
   ,(3, '')            -- empty string
   ,(4, 'test & foo/') -- other branch as last character
   )
SELECT id, (regexp_matches(t, '(&|/|.$)', 'ig'))[1] AS delim
FROM   x;
```

But it fails for empty strings.
And it fails if the last character happens to match another branch. Like: `'foo/bar/'`.
And it isn't perfect to have the actual final character returned. An empty string would be much preferable.

[-> SQLfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1323)

Answer (score 1):

the same occurs for example in C# in which I had the same problem recently so I think this is a normal behaviour for regexps

this is because `$` doesn't stand for a specific sign but a specific position instead
so `$` doesn't really match anything and the position of parser stays in the same position

you need to change your convention a little;

to test for an empty string you can use `^$`